# Square root of type int32 variable

Tags: matlab

I tried to calculate the square root of a type **int32** variable using the `sqrt()` function, but I got this error: **Undefined function 'sqrt' for input arguments of
type 'int32'.**  Then I found that there's a function called `isqrt()` that calculates the square root of type integer variables but it doesn't exist in my Matlab version (R2013a). I tried to download this function but I can't find it. I tried powering the value to (1/2) but integers can only be raised to positive integral powers.

So is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own `isqrt` using an anonymous function:

```
%// variable
A = int32(16)

%// helper function
isqrt = @(x) int32(sqrt(double(x)))

%// root
iroot = isqrt(A)
```

This function should just used as that, if you're sure that it actually possible to calculate the root, as casting a decimal value to `int32(...)` will round it, without displaying an error.

So to make it a little more robust, you could create a function like:

```
function iroot = isqrt(integer)

    root = sqrt(double(integer));
    if mod(root,1) == 0
        iroot = int32( root );
    else
        disp('Input has no integer root')
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that avoids rounding that happens when you convert from double to an integer type by using [`fix`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html) and also it supports any integer type by using [`cast`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cast.html) and [`class`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) functions:

```
isqrt = @(x) cast(fix(sqrt(double(x))), class(x));
```

So for example:

```
>> isqrt(int32(15))
ans =
    3
```

However

```
>> int32(sqrt(double(int32(15))))
ans =
           4
```

Use `fix` instead of `floor` to handle negative values correctly:

```
>> isqrt(int8(-15))
ans =
    0 +    3i
```